# PyQt5 application chrashing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am initially making a **system tray** then trying to open a window from a menu action through a click event.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 300)


def quitApp():
    sys.exit()


def startApp():
    smallApp = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    smallApp.processEvents()
    smallApp.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)

    # Load the icon
    icon = QIcon("logo.png")
    # Creating the Tray
    tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
    tray.setIcon(icon)
    tray.setVisible(True)
    # Creating the Menu
    menu = QMenu()
    """ Creating Actions """
    # Creating Quit Action
    quitAction = QAction('Quit')
    quitAction.triggered.connect(quitApp)
    menu.addAction(quitAction)

    # Creating the App
    attendance_action = QAction('Attendance')
    attendance_action.triggered.connect(startApp)
    menu.addAction(attendance_action)

    tray.setContextMenu(menu)
    app.exec_()
```

---

### Problem

The window is opening for a short period of time and then the application is **crashing**.

All I want to do is that my application starts as a **system tray application** and then be able to open a window when needed.

Comment: change to `window = None

def startApp():
    global window
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()`

Comment: If you have any python script that ends unexpectedly then I recommend you run it from the CMD or console as you will get a very informative error message, in this case: *QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running* which clearly states that you cannot have multiple QApplications.